# How do you create answer boxes for your website?

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to find an answer to this question, but I'm not really sure what to look up after trying Google for a while. Basically, I want my website to have a chat box like the one I'm typing in now (with the preview and all) as well as latex support using the opening $ and closing $. Is there any simple way to accomplish this task? So the most essential features I'd want are:

Latex support

Bold/italicize

Hyperlink integration

Image support (embedded)

I'm fairly new to web development, but I'm using Django as my framework. To be clear, if I wanted to build a site with just one page that had this chat box that allowed you to type (with the necessary features) and just post to the same page, how would that be accomplished?

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an Html WYSIWYG editor. One I know, and I have succesfully used is [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/), which has a [plugin for latex](http://moonwave99.github.io/TinyMCELatexPlugin/).
 But I'm shure there are a lot of alternatives out there.